# left Join ON condition and Select where condition difference

Tags: mysql, sql, join, view

I have three tables {animal, food, animal_food}

```
DROP   TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_animal`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_animal` (
    id_animal       INTEGER     NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    name            VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "no name",
    sex             CHAR(1)     NOT NULL DEFAULT "M",
    size            VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT "Mini",
    age             VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT "born",
    hair            VARCHAR(5 ) NOT NULL DEFAULT "short",
    color           VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL DEFAULT "not defined",
    FOREIGN KEY (sex)           REFERENCES `tbl_sexes`    (sex),
    FOREIGN KEY (tamanio)       REFERENCES `tbl_sizes`    (size),
    FOREIGN KEY (age)           REFERENCES `tbl_ages`     (age),
    FOREIGN KEY (hair)          REFERENCES `tbl_hair_length` (hair_length),
    CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_Animal` UNIQUE (`id_animal`)           
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;




DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `tbl_food`; 
CREATE TABLE `tbl_food` (
    id_food       INTEGER       NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    type_food     VARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL DEFAULT "Other",
    label         VARCHAR(50)   NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT `uc_Info_Food`   UNIQUE  (`id_food`)     
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;


DROP    TABLE IF EXISTS `animal_food`; 
CREATE  TABLE `animal_food` (
    id_animal       INTEGER     NOT NULL,
    food            VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
    quantity        VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",        
    times           VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
    description     VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",            
    date_last   DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',     
    date_water      DATE DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
    CONSTRAINT fk_ID_Animal_Food FOREIGN KEY (id_animal) REFERENCES `tbl_animal`(id_animal)  
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

And I have a view where I select the values columns in animal and animal_food depending on ID

```
CREATE VIEW `CAT_animal_food` AS
       SELECT a.name, a.sex,a.size,a.age,a.hair,a.color,
              a_f.*  
       FROM  `tbl_animal` a, `animal_food` a_f
       WHERE a.id_animal = a_f.id_animal;
```

What would be  better to create a view like above or, to join these animal and animal_food tables?

```
SELECT ...
  FROM A.table t1
  JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column = t1.col
```

What is really the diference between that kind of view and a left join for example?

Comment: `VIEW`s are horrible in `MySQL`. I rather use plain query than wrapping it as a `VIEW`. see: [MySQL VIEW as performance troublemaker](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/08/12/mysql-view-as-performance-troublemaker/)

Comment: so it´s better to avoid this view  thing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference between the two `SELECT` statements is the syntax style.  Both perform **INNER JOINS**.  In other words, this style uses what is called "implicit" syntax:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM A.table t1, B.table2 t2
  WHERE t2.column = t1.col
```

It is "implicit" because the join condition is implied by the `WHERE` clause.  This version uses "explicit" syntax:

```
SELECT ...
  FROM A.table t1
  JOIN B.table2 t2 ON t2.column = t1.col
```

Most people prefer to see "explicit" syntax because it make your code easier to follow; the join condition is explicitly understood and any `WHERE` clause is obvious.

None of this is related to `LEFT JOINS` of course.  [Here is a famous link](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html) with a great visual description of join types.

Answer (score -1):

There is a big difference.

The old school style using a list of tables only allows *inner* joins.

Further, placing non-key conditions in the ON clause of a proper join allows greater performance and capability that a where clause can not deliver. The primary reason for this is that the ON clause is evaluated as the join is being made, but the WHERE clause is evaluated after all joins have been made.

The subject is too complex to do justice here.

Comment: Does **f aliased** mean something or is it a typo?  And I'm guessing this WHERE clause behavior (happening after all joins made) is particular to MySQL, correct?

Comment: @BobDuell oops typo - it was meant to be *evaluated* (fixed now, no thanks to iPhone auto-correct). And "No" - this behaviour is true for all databases. The WHERE clause *filters* the result set. The ON clause controls the join. There are some queries that can *only* be achieved using conditions in the ON clause.

Comment: Wasn't me; I asked a question on the DBA site here: http://dba.stackexchange.com/q/36391/19088

Comment: @Bohemian: because the part: *"a proper join allows greater performance and capability that a where clause can not deliver"* is plainly wrong.

Comment: @ypercube I will concede that *some* databases are able to optimize a where-based query into a join-with-non-key-conditions query, but many don't. Regarding capability, it's just true (how do you do an outer join without a join?). I'm prepared to back what I say with concrete examples that irrefutably demonstrate the veracity of my statement. But I can't be bothered :)

Comment: My objection is related to performance alone and to MySQL in particular. But which other DBMS are you referring to, that can't optimize this, I'm really curious. In all other matters, I agree with you. I am definitely in favour of the explicit `JOIN` synatx.